# What else besides firewall prevents access

Tags: ms-security-essentials, windows-firewall

I have a couple different servers running on my Win7 Pro box - IIS at port 80 and a music streaming server (subsonic) running on 8080. Both respond to 'http://localhost' but neither respond to 'http://[myIPAddy]:port'

I've turned the firewall off and get the same result. Windows Firewall w/AS and MS Security Essentials. I've also tried it with my router's 'block anon requests' to off. What else could be getting in the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need a portforwarding from your router to your win7 box.
Should be something like:
Forward incoming Port 80 to IPofYourWin7Box on Port 80
and something similiar for Port 8080

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your server is binding to all IPs by running `netstat -na | findstr LISTENING`

Binding is OK if you a line like :

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

You server is only listening on localhost if the line look like the following. In this case you need to adjust your streaming server configuration

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```